# Python interactive plot with user input

Tags: python

I am having an issue in interaction with the plot while using input.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2]
y = x
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
a = input('Enter:')
```

Here, after the execution of plt.show() a plot window pops up but it remains un-responsive until I provide some user input to "a".
I want to have a look at the plot and then I want to pass the input to "a".

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.ion()
```

Please add this line before plotting, it will enable your interactive mode.

See the documentation, :

```
def ion():
    'Turn interactive mode on.'
    matplotlib.interactive(True)
    install_repl_displayhook()
```